# change the submit method of a jquery POST form

Tags: jquery

i have 2 jquery codes. How can i put this toghether.

example

if checkbox is checked use

```
<script>

$(document).ready(LoadMe);
 function LoadMe()
{
$('#msg_text').bind('keypress', function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if(code == 13 && !e.shiftKey) // Enter key is pressed     
   {
     var msg = $("#msg_text").val();
var ontvanger = $("#ontvanger").val();
if ( $.trim( $('#msg_text').val() ) == '')
{

}
else
{
 $("#send_msg").hide();
 $("#dis_sub").show();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
   url: "post_message.php",
data: { msg: msg, ontvanger: ontvanger},
cache: false,
success: function(html){

$("#msg_text").val('');
$("#content").prepend(html);
$("#dis_sub").hide();
$("#send_msg").show();
}
});
 }return false; 
   }
});
```

}

else use

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
$("#send_msg").click(function() 
{
 var msg = $("#msg_text").val();
var ontvanger = $("#ontvanger").val();
if ( $.trim( $('#msg_text').val() ) == '')
{

}
else
{
$("#send_msg").hide();
$("#dis_sub").show();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "post_message.php",
data: { msg: msg, ontvanger: ontvanger},
cache: false,
success: function(html){

$("#msg_text").val('');
$("#content").prepend(html);
$("#dis_sub").hide();
$("#send_msg").show();
}
});
}return false;
}); });
</script>
```

if checkbox is checked i want to submit my form with a enter key else submit the form with click on a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add if condition to check whether check box is checked or not. you can use jQuery `is()` function with proper selection eg: `is('#id_of_the_chekbox:cheked')`, use css pseudo selector :checked then call your functions in true and false conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Put your submit code in a function say `submit_form()`. Then bind your events with this function. Check the checkbox status before submit.

```
$('#msg_text').bind('keypress', function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if(code == 13 && !e.shiftKey && checkbox.checked) submit_form();
});

$("#send_msg").click(function () {
    if (!checkbox.checked) submit_form();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function LoadMe(){

    $('#msg_text').bind('keypress', function(e){
       do keypress stuff . .  .
    }else{
       do normal submit stuff . . .
    }

}
```

Which will run the 'keypress' code if the key is pressed, otherwise it will run the 'other' code.